# Error in configuring cakephp without database

Tags: php, cakephp

I using the cassandra DB in my application along with cakephp. I have created the the custom datasource like

```
App::uses('DboSource', 'Model/Datasource');
class CassndraDb extends DboSource
{
    var $description = "This is a temporary driver for cassandra";
    function connect()
    {
        $this->connected = true;
        return $this->connected;
    }
    function disconnect()
    {
        $this->connected = false;
        return !$this->connected;
    }
    function value($string)
    {
        return "\0".$string."\0";
    }
}
```

And my database file looks like

```
public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'CassndraDb',
            );
```

I have configured the cakephp outside the app so that my two application can run share core cakephp libraries.

I have two problems

1. Cakephp does not honor app/Model/Datasource/source_files. And gives
   an error    "Error: Datasource class CassndraDb could not be found.
   ". When I copy the datasource to cake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/
   then only cakephp honors datasource.
2. When I copy the datasource file to 
   "cake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/" it gives series of errors.

I dont know whats the problem with cakephp but it tries to connect to database though I have `public $useTable = false;` set. I tried to debug but stuck with non-sense of cakephp.

Does anybody have idea about this? Please help.

Thanks in Advance
Manish

Comment: "it gives series of errors." - What errors...?

Comment: What's the output of var_dump(App::path('Model/Datasource'));

Comment: Output of var_dump(App::path('Model/Datasource'));  is array(1) { [0]=> string(34) "<root>/app/Model/Datasource/" }

Comment: Strange thing is, it tries to connect to database. That is very very strange. Why it should connect to database when application is configured not to user any.

Comment: Your application IS CONFIGURED to use a DB because you defined the `$default` datasource in `database.php`.
Your issue with the loading of your custom class is there because of some `PATH` issues. Check your paths! Check where you're loading stuff from. It is not 'CakePHP non-sense' it is more-likely you who doesn't understand what's going on exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh !!! I debugged issue. Its due to wrong names of couple of model files. Error message of cakephp is really deceptive. In the first glance I thought its DB connection related issue.

@Borislav Sabev : I also tried with empty database config class and useTable set to false in all models. Irrespective of the database config and useTable setting cakephp do try to connect to database. I think they must introduce some kind of configuration setting that can turn off the DB connection part.